# SoundJS: Firefox is not able to play a mp3

Tags: javascript, firefox, soundjs

I am currently working on a website that includes a musicplayer made with SoundJS.
I, myself, am using Google Chrome to test and debug my website, and it worked like a charm, but when I recently tested it in FireFox, I noticed this strange error.

When I hit the play button and the sound is being registered I get this error:

`The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type`

The code I use in my javascript file to create the soundInstance:
'response' is a string containing the location of the .mp3 file (this all works perfectly in Chrome).

```
createjs.Sound.registerSound('uploads/songs/'+response,'song');
```

When I test this same piece of code with an 'ogg' file it works perfectly in FireFox.
I also heard from some people that it doesn't work in Safari too, but unfortunatly I am a windows user.

If you want to test it for yourself:
www.playmesome.be . Just hit the play button and it will keep on loading infinitely because of this error.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Is this a question or a statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a [known issue](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/SoundJS/classes/WebAudioPlugin.html) with Firefox on windows that does not load all mp3 files properly, and therefore it is recommended that you load another supported file type first (such as ogg).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have to add to this that the encoding of a mp3 file can add extra problems as you can read here [link](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/issues/101).